# JavaScript editing in Chrome does not take effect

Tags: javascript

I'm editing a script in a page with that code:

```js
 if(($email.val()).isEmail() == false){
  
  $errorTip($email,"Imvalid email.");
  $email.focus();
  return false;
 }
```

I'm trying to learn bypassing input restrictions on my localhost test site. I type an invalid format of an email address and I get an error, obviously.

I right clicked the page, "Inspect Element" then deleted the whole if statement.
When I try again to submit the invalid email, it gives me the same error
Seems like it does not take effect that way, any idea how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you press ctrl+S after editing the file?

Comment: That makes Chrome ask me to save the html file on my computer. Doesn't work

Comment: Try to put cursor into edited file, not webpage

Comment: That's what I've been doing, same thing with Firefox.

Comment: What is your OS and Chrome version?

Comment: Windows 7Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Do you see star (*) after the name of the file as here https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDBiu.png?

Comment: I edit the script through the whole page source like this picture: https://i.ibb.co/vVD34kq/image.png

Comment: You should extract code to separate JS file and then edit it through the sources tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit JavaScript in **element** tab or **sources** tab of debugger tool it will not update the changes as like HTML change. JavaScript codes are executed when page is loaded.
To apply changes just paste the javaScript code in **console** tab and press enter, that will affect the change to your page.